# ROR Search virtual fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, pg

I am just adding search to my project to be able to find people by name. but on my db i have `first_name` and `last_name`  but if someone searches for a full name like **Joe Doe** no result matches

```
#model 
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    (self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name).titleize
  end
end

#controller 
class PeoplesController < ApplicationController
  expose(:peoples){
    if params[:search]
      People.where(
        "first_name ILIKE ?
         OR last_name ILIKE ?
         ", params[:search], params[:search]
      )
    else
      People.all
    end
  }
end
```

Again if someone searches a first_name  it comes back with results, last_name  it comes back with results but not for a full name

and if i try to add `full_name`  to the query i get **column "full_name" does not exist**

Thanks for the help

Comment: what you are missing is `"%#{params[:search]}%"`

Comment: the problem is not the wild card search is that i also want to search for the combine values of firs_name + last_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A virtual field is not on database-level. You can't do database-based search without explaining what that virtual field is to the database.

The definition of your field is essentially a list of columns it consists of. Since you are using PostgreSQL, you could leverage its full-text searching capabilities by [using `pg_search`](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search). It's well able to search by multiple columns at once.

In fact, in the docs there is an example of how to do it that almost exactly matches your case. I literally just copy-pasted it here. [Go figure.](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#searching-against-multiple-columns)

```ruby
# Model
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, :against => [:first_name, :last_name]
end

# Example code for the Rails console
person_1 = Person.create!(:first_name => "Grant", :last_name => "Hill")
person_2 = Person.create!(:first_name => "Hugh", :last_name => "Grant")

Person.search_by_full_name("Grant") # => [person_1, person_2]
Person.search_by_full_name("Grant Hill") # => [person_1]
```

Is that sort of thing worth an extra dependency, is up to you. If you find yourself in situation of constructing many complicated searches, this might help.

Comment: Love your solution I have to say thanks this really help me out a lot .

Answer (score 0):

> Again if someone searches a first_name it comes back with results, last_name it comes back with results but not for a full name

That's expected because none of the fields contain the whole name, just the parts, hence they can never match. A simple way out of this is to just split the seatch term by space and check whether you got two or more items.

```
# app/queries/people_search_query.rb
class PeopleSearchQuery
  attr_reader :relation

  def initialize(relation = Person.all)
    @relation = relation
  end

  def search(params)
    if params[:search]
      where_str = "first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ?"
      split     = params[:search].split(" ", 2)

      if split.size > 1
        relation.where(where_str, *split)
      else
        relation.where(where_str, *(split * 2))
      end
    else
      relation
    end
  end
end

class PeoplesController < ApplicationController
  expose(:peoples) { PeopleSearchQuery.new.search(params) }
end
```